# How to configure nginx the way url shows less folder than it's real?

Tags: nginx

I have app on Node.js on Nginx.

When I open page

```
domainname.com/somefolder/page.html
```

it should show in address bar the same page

```
domainname.com/somefolder/page.html
```

But page.html can be on the page deep in folder like

```
morefolder/anotherfolder/…./somefolder
```

Meanwhile I have folders, which are located in core folder and should open from this folder. How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by configuring nginx as below:

```
 server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  domainname.com www.domainname.com;
        #root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location /somefolder/page.html {
          root  morefolder/anotherfolder/onemorefolder;
        }
    }
```

Your core folder is morefolder/anotherfolder/onemorefolder

All subfolders and html pages are within.

You browse `domainname.com/somefolder/page.html` it re-directs it to `domainname.com/morefolder/anotherfolder/onemorefolder/somefolder/page.html` but this is transparent to user and address bar shows same page you browsed.

Comment: is was example. name of the folder "somefolder" and file "page" all always different

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have exact name of files and folders I used this construction

```
location / { 
    try_files $uri /post$uri =404;
}
```

`location /` checks any URL which is not specified (i.e. domainname.com/test). In my case it was any URL like `domainname.com/folder/file.html`

`try_files` checks URL (aka $uri) and if it is not found then goes to next `/post$uri` and if it's not found, then shows 404 page

In my case i open page `www.domainname.com/folder/file.html` it checks whether it exists, it doesn't exist, then it checks whether `www.domainname.com/post/folder/file.html` exist and opens it if it exist, otherwise shows 404 page